# Change filename prefix in Path PosixPath object

Tags: python, regex, string, path

I need to change a prefix for a current file.

An example would look as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path
file = Path('/Users/my_name/PYTHON/Playing_Around/testing_lm.py')
# Current file with destination
print(file)

# Prefix to be used
file_prexif = 'A'

# Hardcoding wanted results.
Path('/Users/my_name/PYTHON/Playing_Around/A_testing_lm.py')
```

As can be seen hardcoding it is easy. However is there a way to automate this step?
There is a pseudo - idea of what I want to do:

```
str(file).split('/')[-1] = str(file_prexif) + str('_') + str(file).split('/')[-1]
```

I only want to change last element of `PosixPath` file. However it is not possible to change only last element of string

Answer (score 5):

`file.stem` accesses the base name of the file without extension.

`file.with_stem()` (added in Python 3.9) returns an updated `Path` with a new stem:

```py
from pathlib import Path
file = Path('/Users/my_name/PYTHON/Playing_Around/testing_lm.py')
print(file.with_stem(f'A_{file.stem}'))
```

```
\Users\my_name\PYTHON\Playing_Around\A_testing_lm.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [file.parent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) to get the parent of the path and [file.name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) to get the final path component, excluding the drive and root.

```py
from pathlib import Path
file = Path('/Users/my_name/PYTHON/Playing_Around/testing_lm.py')

file_prexif_lst = ['A','B','C']

for prefix  in file_prexif_lst:
    p = file.parent.joinpath(f'{prefix}_{file.name}')
    print(p)
```

```
/Users/my_name/PYTHON/Playing_Around/A_testing_lm.py
/Users/my_name/PYTHON/Playing_Around/B_testing_lm.py
/Users/my_name/PYTHON/Playing_Around/C_testing_lm.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Mark Tolonen's answer, but using the `file.with_name` method (which is easier for me to remember than "stem")

```py
from pathlib import Path

file = Path('/home/python/myFile.py')
prefix = 'hello'

new_file = file.with_name(f"{prefix}_{file.name}")
print(new_file)
```

```
OUTPUT:
/home/python/hello_myFile.py
```